# How to compare char/string?

Tags: visual-c++

How to declare and compare the strings?

```
// test ="my test string";

char testDest[256];
char *p= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(URL->bstrVal);
strcpy(testDest, p);
```

How can I compare test with testDest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non case sensitive comparisons try int `strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 )`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

If you want the string comparing to be case sensitive, i.e. `"test" != "TEsT"`, use `int memcmp ( const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2, size_t num )`.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/

So:

```
typedef char string[];
string sz1 = "This is a test string."
string sz2 = "This is a test string."
string sz3 = "This Is A Test String."
if(memcmp(sz1, sz2, strlen(sz1) > strlen(sz2) ? strlen(sz1) : strlen(sz2)) == 0)
    printf("sz1 and sz2 are equal");
else
    printf("sz1 and sz2 are not equal");
if(memcmp(sz1, sz3, strlen(sz1) > strlen(sz2) ? strlen(sz1) : strlen(sz2)) == 0)
    printf("sz1 and sz3 are equal");
else
    printf("sz1 and sz3 are not equal");
if(strcmp(sz2, sz3) == 0)
    printf("sz2 and sz3 are equal");
else
    printf("sz2 and sz3 are not equal");
```

EDIT: You can also use stricmp() for case sensitive comparisons.

Comment: strcmp is "exact", if by "exact", you mean case sensitive. The case-insensitive variant is called stricmp.

Comment: `stricmp` does not exist in the C99 Standard Library. You mean POSIX perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp`. But I would suggest you go through a book on C programming first.